# How do I properly set the navigation controller font size?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to set my navigation controller title font size programatically and using UIKit. It works whenever my view controller with the nav controller first appears, but when I navigate to the next controller and try to set the font size there with the same code block, the navigation bar title first has the default font size then scales to the set font size. Similarly, when I navigate back from this controller to the original controller that worked properly when it was first pulled up, it starts at the default font size then changes to the set font size. How do I get it so when the view controller is shown, the navigation title text is already set? I've already tried for both view controllers putting this code block in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, and the willShow delegate function of navigation controller. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size:  30) {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [

            NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,

            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white

        ]

    }

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .sBlue

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Unless you need to support iOS 12 or earlier, you should use `UINavigationBarAppearance` to customize the nav bar.

Comment: Which function are you trying to run that code inside viewDidLoad or another function ?

Comment: @HangarRash I have updated the script to use UINavigationBarAppearance to customize the nav bar however I am still facing the same issue. Any other clue as to what might be happening?

Comment: @AhmedMohiy Currently yes I moved it back to viewDidLoad but I have also triedviewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, and the willShow delegate function of the navigation controller, none of which have worked

Comment: @CarLordVR Is it working now ?  if you want to update anything before it appears on the screen you have to use viewDidLoad

Comment: @AhmedMohiy Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

You can add this inside your app delegate function application(_ application:,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size:  30) {
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
            
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
            
        ]
        
    }
```

and it will work for all your navigation bars

Comment: Ahmed, thank you, however I need it to be changed specifically just for this navigation bar and not for all in the app. Is there some way I can do that?

Comment: I see can you share more info to be able to help you more. You can add gifs or screenshots to see that behavior and if you like to share more about that screen code that will be helpful.